# need get link text from selected li menu with jquery

Tags: jquery

when i click on my li menu, i need get this link text. The problem is that the menu is a tree and i get a current text with parent text.

For example - when i clik on "test 3" i also get and "test 2". In this situation i need get only "test 3".

I can change only jquery script, html code generate cms.

My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu li").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).children('a').text();
        alert(text);        
    });
});
</script>
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">test 2</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#menu li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var target = e.target,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;
    console.log(text);        
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xLsWX/).

Comment: Then I'm glad to have helped! =)

Answer (score 1):

why not listen on the `a` element then?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        alert(text);        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VQMqm/

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation to use a single listener and listen on the anchors like others suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);

    // Anchors are navigation, and the default action is to
    // load the "href" attribute. Calling 'preventDefault'
    // prevents that navigation.
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```